# Explain karma unit test times

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I've been searching the web for this for two days and I found nothing. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong way — I don't know...

So here it is: what are the times on my console when running a Karma+Jasmine+phantomJs unit test?

```
... Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.878 secs / 0.112 secs)
```

First, I though that the second time is the total unit test time (for example, when running multiple tasks), however, sometimes the first time gets to be 'bigger', sometimes not...

Anyone?

Comment: Load time / execution time?  I have no idea.  I even read the thesis on Karma written by the inventor and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Hahaha! Thanks for the effort.. I don't know! :P

Comment: But I'm quite surprised that not even the thesis includes it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**total time / net time**

- net time = only test execution (in the browser)
- total time = how long it took since Karma noticed the file change till the final result was printed (net time + communication with the browser + loading the files in the browser)

See [karma/lib/reporters/base.js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/65080f535d34c02222c030974ff5acbe3287d0ab/lib/reporters/base.js#L38)

Comment: Although, I'd assume total time includes net time as well, therefore, it could never be less than that. You can see it in my example that the total time is actually less than the net time...